# Eval can't use aliases in file

Tags: bash, eval, alias

I am trying to understand why `eval` is treating aliases differently inside a file vs the cli.  When I ask `eval` to use a command with an alias in it in the program, it cannot find it.  On the cli it has no problem with it.  Also alias shows that the bash environment is aware of the alias.

**test.sh**

```
alias ECHO='echo'
cmd="ECHO dog"
alias
eval $cmd
eval "ECHO dog"
```

**Execution**

```
$ bash test.sh
alias ECHO='echo'
test.sh: line 4: ECHO: command not found
test.sh: line 5: ECHO: command not found

$ alias ECHO='echo'
$ alias
alias ECHO='echo'
$ cmd="ECHO dog"
$ eval $cmd
dog
$ eval "ECHO dog"
dog
```

Comment: Aliases are turned off in scripts by default. They're an interactive feature only (included in an annex to the POSIX standard that's specific to interactive shells). Use functions instead.

Comment: `ECHO() { echo "$@"; }`

Comment: Also, don't use `eval $cmd` -- it has some obscure but dangerous bugs, even if it looks like the quoting inside `cmd` is correct. Use `eval "$cmd"` instead.

Comment: See the `expand_aliases` mention in the answer to the linked duplicate re: turning aliases back on in scripts -- _but_ whether that's available is very dependent on your shell; if you're in a shell compiled without interactive extensions aliases may not exist at all..

Comment: (BTW, to be clear, "use functions instead" is intended to be general advice, not just for cases where you outright _can't_ use aliases; the only compelling use cases for aliases even in interactive shells are places where you want to be able to write code that the parser will refuse to process without prefix replacement being performed; there are use cases for that, but they're very rare)

Comment: BTW, you don't need `eval` to repro this behavior. If you'd tried just putting `ECHO dog` in your script on its own, you would have seen the same problem.

Comment: (*use `eval "$cmd"` instead* above should have been followed with "...if you must use `eval` at all"; [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) discusses why `eval` is frowned on, and many of the extensions that bash has on top of POSIX sh are _specifically_ to allow safer ways to do indirect assignment, indirect expansion, and several other classes of operation that in baseline POSIX shells are only possible with use of `eval`).

Comment: Thank you,  I had assumed it was some sort of shell issue, but that makes sense.  The function approach worked perfectly